# Powershell to create a new registry value

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a new registry value in this path "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security"
It should be a new "DWORD" inside the security key called "VBAWarnings" and value should be one.

I have tried the following way:

```
New-ItemProperty –Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security" -Value "VBAWarnings"  -PropertyType "DWORD"
```

However it is not creating anything and not sure whats per error message I have "

```
((Get-Process MicrosoftEdgeCP -ErrorA.ps1:1 char:124
+ ... ce\16.0\Outlook\Security" -Value "VBAWarnings"  -PropertyType "DWORD"
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString"
```

Comment: You need a name for the property.

Comment: Like @AdminOfThings I think you mixed up `value` and `name`... I assume the `value` will be `1` and the name is `"VBAWarnings"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been correctly answered by @AdminOfThings and @Neko Musume. I'd like to add the step of displaying the finished code, as well as how to address this in the future. First, the code:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security" -Name "VBAWarnings" -PropertyType "DWORD" -Value "1"
```

Whenever you are creating new powershell code, use Powershell ISE (Integrated Scripting Engine). The nice thing about this interface is that it has intellisense, popping up useful things are you're writing your code.

To replicate this, in the scripting portion of the ISE window (the white part), I typed:

```
New-Itemproperty -
```

When I added the dash, it gave me a list of items to choose from. I chose the top one, which was path. I then continued the code:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security" -
```

Again, it showed me a list of options, and I went with the top choice, Name. Continued until I saw the default choices (things like -force). This is a good rule of thumb when you're working with commands in powershell.

Comment: And because it is a DWORD, remove the quotes from the value --> `-PropertyType "DWORD" -Value 1`